# Пробелы мужду изображениями

Tags: html, css

Доброго всем дня.

[image: Вот]

Как убрать эти пробелы в следующем коде:

```
<style>
    html {
        margin: 0;
        background-color: black;
    }

    body {
        width: 1300px;
        /*margin: 0 auto;*/
        background-color: gray;
    }
    img {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        /*float: left;*/
        text-align: left;
    }

    #images {
        width: 1250px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="images">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="img1"/>
        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="img2"/>
        <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="img3"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

при таких требованиях:

1) тэги  располагать в **разных** строках;
 2) не использовать `float: left` в стиле для img.

Comment: А почему не хотите использовать float: left? Дело в том, что это обычный пробел, как между словами, так как изображение является строчно-блочным элементом. Если не хотите делать изображения плавающими, то задайте им display: block и позиционируйте с помощью position: absolute;

Comment: Потому что при плавающем left все изображения сбиваются влево, что влечет дальнейшее выравнивание всего блока изображение или добавления подблока... Не суть. А вот блочными-то как раз мне и делать не нужно)

Comment: Не понял вашу проблему, ну да ладно. В таком случае вы можете просто задать изображениям отрицательный margin-left.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

и там же есть ссылка на http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант:

```
    <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="img1"/
   ><img src="img/2.jpg" alt="img2"/
   ><img src="img/3.jpg" alt="img3"/>
```

Можете подробнее прочитать [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/189118/).

Comment: хаха))) интересный вариант) но вариант с "межблочными" комментариями мне больше нравится) спасибо за статейку)

Comment: Не за что, но, ИМХО, комментарии засоряют читабельность кода. А отрицательные марджины очень плохо себя ведут при "нестандартных шрифтах" и в адаптивных дизайнах.

Answer (score 0):

Margin для img примените по бокам.

Comment: А разве {margin: 0} с боков не убирает?

Comment: @nightin_gal, нет, я же вам написал выше, что дело не в margin. А @artem328 имел в виду отрицательный margin.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик) Ваш коммент я сразу не увидел. Отрицательный налагает проблемы с IE6, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: А зачем вам IE6?

Comment: МНЕ - не за чем) Но я же не в ответе за пользователей, которых мы приручили нашими интернетами)

Comment: Процент пользователей IE6 в рунете - 0.1%. Спрашивается, нужно ли это делать ради 0.1% бабулек и дедулек?

Comment: Нету уже давно никакого IE6, забудьте. Постарайтесь забыть. Понимаю, что трудно забыть такое травмирующее воспоминание, но всё же. Нету больше в природе такого явления, как IE6, всё, финита, расслабьтесь.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы убрать проблемы между элементами, нужно убрать пробелы между элементами (:
Переводы строк в HTML интерпретируются, как пробелы, из-за этого возникают такие вот спецэффекты в инлайновом контексте.

Можно, например, поместить все теги в одну строку (или использовать финт ушами, описанный [[@nim](/users/22966/nim)](/users/22966/nim)).

Можно задать нулевой размер шрифта для содержимого `#images` (если там где-то должен быть текст, то размер шрифта придётся потом восстанавливать).

Можно использовать [списочный элемент](http://htmlbook.ru/html/type/list) вместо набора `<img>`-ов. Это, кстати, будет правильнее с точки зрения семантики и вообще.

P.S. В 2014 году делать элементы меню картинками - моветон. Само меню - список, градиент задать через [css linear-gradient](http://htmlbook.ru/css3-na-primerakh/lineinyi-gradient) или через фоновую картинку шириной в один пиксель с `background-repeat: repeat-x` (если нужна поддержка IE9 и старше), текст сделать простым текстом, иконку вставить через шрифт (ну или как background-image дополнительного пустого элемента, или как background-image у элемента списка).